# how to fix the unexpected character error in json

Tags: php, reactjs, apache

I have a react project which get data from an API folder in ht-docs in easyphp which include file .htaccess and index.php.
and a postData.js which have the URL of the API folder.

The problem is when i click on the button to submit i get an error in the console

`Syntax Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

this is the login function in the class of login component

```
login() {
    if(this.state.username && this.state.password){
       PostData('login',this.state).then((result) => {
        let responseJson = result;
        if(responseJson.userData){
          sessionStorage.setItem('userData',JSON.stringify(responseJson));
          this.setState({redirectToReferrer: true});
         }
         else
             alert(result.error);
      });
    }
}
```

this is the login function in index.php

```
function AddMaterial() 
{ 
    require 'config.php'; 
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 
    $username = $json['username']; $password = $json['pass']; 
    $userData =''; $query = "select * from tb where name='$username' and pass='$password'"; 
    $result= $db->query($query);
    $rowCount=$result->num_rows;

    if($rowCount>0)
    {
        $userData = $result->fetch_object();
        $user_id=$userData->id;
        $userData = json_encode($userData);
        echo '{"userData":'.$userData.'}';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '{"error":"Wrong username and password"}';
    }
}
```

Comment: What does line 1 column 1 of the JSON data look like?

Comment: Do not try to roll your own json. Create an object or an array, and use `json_encode()` on it. Also check the response tab in you Developer Tools to find out exactly what is being returned.

Comment: i dont know :/ im learning react new and i found this on enternet and seems to be gd but this error is stuck